# a problem using LSTM network (neural networks)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, lstm

im trying to create a speaker diarization system using lstm (im trying to make the network tell the difference between speakers).
this is the model i've created:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(768, batch_input_shape=(39, 40, 1), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(LSTM(768, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(LSTM(768, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(4))
```

there are 4 different speakers.
in my dataset i have the array 'features' (256 at length for 256 speech segments).
for each segment in 'features' i have 39 vectors to represent each segment and each of these vectors is at size 40.
each of these 39 vectors is extracted from a different time window. (i used log mel filterbank energies).
i also have the array 'lables' which is also 256 at length and contains the lables for each segment.
i used 'to_categorical' for it:

```
labels = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(labels, num_classes=4)
```

i tried using a generator to feed it to the network but it didnt work.
this is the class i used:

```
class KerasBatchGenerator(object):

    def __init__(self, features,  batch_size, labels):
        self.features = features
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.labels = labels

    def generate(self):
        while True:
            for i in self.labels:  
                for j in self.features: 
                    temp = [j, i]
                 #   temp = np.expand_dims(temp, axis=1)
                    temp = np.expand_dims(temp, axis=2)
                    yield tuple(temp)
```

and the code i used to run the network is:

```
train_data_generator = KerasBatchGenerator(features, batch_size, labels)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit_generator(train_data_generator.generate(), 100, 1)
```

please help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i guessed correctly, you want to classify which input in spoke by which speaker.
In that case your final layer should have a shape (batch_size, numOfClasses) or (39, 4)

But if you take close look at the summary the output shape for final layer is (39, 40, 4)

to get the proper shape remove the argument  return_sequences=True  from last LSTM layer.

Comment: thanks for the help. i did what you said and it does alter the output size but i still need to figure out how to feed the data properly using the generator and im struggling with that..

Comment: Loading big dataset in RAM generally creates problem and generating data using generator differs from data to data. In your case to answer it first i need to understand how your data is organised at directory level and type of files(features, labels). You can  also follow the links [https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/]  [https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Sequence]

Comment: sure. i've uploaded both files using pickle. heres the adress:https://gofile.io/d/atdczX

Comment: ok, i got your data where feature = (256, 39, 40) , labels = (256, 4) As per the shape of data I'm supposing that it is only one batch with size 256 . Now here is question you're having trouble in feeding the data to your model or loading the complete data to your RAM

Comment: feeding to the model is the problem

Comment: yeah. i made this function based on an unrelated example but as you can see its not working properly.. do you any idea how to fix it?

Comment: First problem comes from function generate: In function **i** have shape (4, )  and **j** have shape (39, 40) . It is correct you can concat them temp = [j, i]. But while using any numpy method numpy convert it into ** numpy array** and a list(temp) with different shapes of item(i, j) can't be converted into **np array**. If i and j have same shapes it would work

Comment: And second problem is in your model input shape. If would like to refer this article [https://medium.com/@shivajbd/understanding-input-and-output-shape-in-lstm-keras-c501ee95c65e] before moving further

Comment: i've changed the model input to be:batch_input_shape=(256, 39, 40). so it wil fit the size of the data. also turned features into an array.. and also changed the fitting function so im no longer using a generator but the regulat fit function:model.fit(features_array, labels, 256, 1). and i am getting the following line:

Comment: the line: Epoch 1/10
2020-07-06 17:44:55.928423: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1502] OP_REQUIRES failed at variable_ops.cc:104 : Already exists: Resource __per_step_27/Adam_6/gradients/lstm_19/while/ReadVariableOp/Enter_grad/ArithmeticOptimizer/AddOpsRewrite_Add/tmp_var/struct tensorflow::TemporaryVariableOp::TmpVar                       do you have any idea what it means?

Comment: if you are providing batch_input_shape then it is not a good idea to provide batch_shape in model.fit()

Comment: ok so i changed the fit() to be model.fit(features_array, labels, epochs=10).   now i get this error: tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.AlreadyExistsError: Resource __per_step_33/Adam_6/gradients/lstm_19/while/ReadVariableOp/Enter_grad/ArithmeticOptimizer/AddOpsRewrite_Add/tmp_var/struct tensorflow::TemporaryVariableOp::TmpVar
  [[{{node Adam_6/gradients/lstm_19/while/ReadVariableOp/Enter_grad/ArithmeticOptimizer/AddOpsRewrite_Add/tmp_var}}]]

Comment: so i changed the batch_input_size to batch_input_shape=(1, 39, 40) and now its running smoothly. thanks for all the help!!!